# Why does a button created programmatically in a collection view cell need to be a lazy var?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, lazy-initialization

If I create a button programmatically in a collectionView cell, why do I need to make the button a lazy var and not a constant if I want to trigger an added target?

For example,

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let xButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleX), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func handleX() {
        print("123")
    }

    ...other boiler plate code
}
```

123 never gets printed if the button is selected, but if I set my button to be a lazy var:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    lazy var xButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleX), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func handleX() {
        print("123")
    } 

    ...other boiler plate code
}
```

123 gets printed.

I understand that a lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. It's not obvious to me why it matters for a UIButton.

Comment: You need the creation of the button to be lazy so that you can access `self` which isn't available until after the cell has been created.  Alternatively, you could assign the target/action later.

Comment: @vacawama you should post your comment as an answer. The other person who answered didn't answer the "why" question as well as you did.

Comment: @vacawama If you post your comment as an answer, i'll gladly accept it. It is a good, simple, and easily understood answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the creation of the button to be `lazy` so that you can access `self` which isn't available until after the cell has been created.  So, the issue isn't the creation of the button itself, but the setting of the target/action which needs access to `self`.

Alternatively, you could assign the target/action later when the button is added to the view hierarchy of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to initialize the variable lazily unless you need the instance itself like you do with `addTarget()`.